# Child QGraphicsItem move event (ItemIsMovable) to its parent

Tags: qt, qt4, move, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

How can a child QGraphicsItem move its parent item ?

I set the child item's ItemIsMovable flag  and when I try to move the child item, the parent item does not move, only child item moves.

```
// child items's mouseMoveEvent
void TextDiagram::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
     parentItem()->moveBy(event->pos().x() - lastPos.x() , event->pos().y() -lastPos.y() );
     QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

void TextDiagram::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    lastPos.setX( event->pos().x() );
    lastPos.setY( event->pos().y() );
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}

This works but if I select more than one item, it only moves the item under the mouse.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by invoking parent's mouse events  in child's mouse events .